# Longitudinal and Latitudinal coordinates of interstate exits

Tags: latitude-longitude, transportation, point-of-interest

I need to find the coordinates of all the interstate exits for some research.  I'm not looking to code up a program that will do it for me, but I was hoping that someone had already done it and would be willing to share that information with me.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to GIS Stack Exchange!  To help us understand what you are after would you be able to edit your question to describe what format you are seeking, please? Is it perhaps a *.csv with interstate_highway_no, interstate_exit_no, longitude, latitude?  Are you planning to use any GIS software in your research?

Comment: Googling for `interstate exit poi` turns up [this](http://www.gps-data-team.com/poi/united_states/transportation/Interstate_Exit-US.html).

Comment: @KirkKuykendall - that looks like an Answer to me

Comment: well atleast some of them - from experience this is not easy to find for all states. Many state DoT will provide a list in some format (e.g. PDF) but some don't seem to know or care

Comment: Searching the [tag:POI] tag on our site may turn up some helpful links and additional data sources.

Answer (score 1):

Also, you could try OpenStreetMap datasets, obtainable using the Overpass API, like http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/rt .

This approach will include some programming, though.

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly what I needed.  One more question, with overpass-turbo, is there a way to output more information (city, state, road name) with the data?

Comment: Maybe you can do it. Maybe the folks over at help.openstreetmap.org can help you better with this.

Answer (score 0):

Exits are considered to be "[points of interest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_of_interest)", more commonly known as POI's.

Many data vendors provide POI's.  Googling for `interstate exit POI` turns up a the site of the "GPS Data Team", who provide interstate exit POI's [here](http://www.gps-data-team.com/poi/united_states/transportation/Interstate_Exit-US.html).

Answer (score 0):

For *"personal, non-commercial use"* (see [terms of use](http://www.poi-factory.com/terms)), searching the POI files on [POI-Factory.com](http://www.poi-factory.com) for the [keyword="exit"](http://www.poi-factory.com/search/pfc/exit) turns up quite a few datasets.